# CollectionType Index Tracks Corresponding SequenceType Generator

Tags: swift

Is a `SequenceType`'s `Generator` required to produce `Elements` in the identical order to `Index` `successor()`?  That is, must the following to be true for all collection/sequence types?

```
let str = "Hello!"
var dex = str.startIndex
var gen = str.generate()

while dex != str.endIndex { 
  assert (str[dex] == gen.next()) 
  dex = dex.successor()
}
```

Clearly an `IndexingGenerator<>` will have this property, but must all `Generators`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 'yes'.  The comment in the Swift code defining `CollectionType` is:

```
/// The sequence view of the elements is identical to the collection
/// view.  In other words, the following code binds the same series of
/// values to `x` as does `for x in self {}`::
///
///   for i in startIndex..<endIndex {
///     let x = self[i]
///   }
```

Since `for x in self` invokes the `GeneratorType` interface, the orders generated through the two interfaces must be identical. Implementors of new CollectionTypes are, at best it seems, to use this as guidance.